# Re-exporting scss functions or mixins

Tags: sass

I have the following 3 scss files:

```
// component.scss
@use 'componentFunctions' as componentFunctions;

/** Adding a default color theme to the component **/
@include componentFunctions.addColorTheme(...);
```

```
// componentFunctions.scss

@mixin addColorTheme($param) {
   ... mixin that creates a color theme for the component
}
```

```
// main.scss
@use 'component' as componentName;

/** I would also like to use the createColorTheme mixin in this file, to add a new color theme for this component, in case this module is loaded, how can I achieve this? **/
```

What I am trying to achieve, is to access the `function` defined in `componentFunction.scss`, in the `main.scss` file. The only way I've managed to do this, is to manually redefine the function in the `component.scss` file, but surely there has to be a better way around for this.

Strangely, if I am not re-namespacing my imports, everything works automatically. There is a possibility that I misunderstood how the `@use` functionality works in SCSS, could someone elaborate on how could I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use):

> Any styles loaded this way will be included exactly once in the compiled CSS output, no matter how many times those styles are loaded.

So you can use `@use` again in your `main.scss` file as the code below:

```
@use 'component' as componentName;
@use 'componentFunctions' as componentFunctions;
$newVar: componentFunctions.myFunction();
```

In that way you don't need to **redefine the function in the component.scss**.

Comment: yes, but I would also want to not have to reinclude, for example if I have a deep hierarchical tree all files where I defined a function. Basically, what I want is a component, that creates some stylings, and exposes some functions for the "outside world", without the outside scope having to know about the other modules that specific component uses.

Comment: I could not understand your meaning of ```exposes some functions for the "outside world"```. You defined your function in a separate file! I think you made the situation so **complicated**! If a component needs a special function for itself only, so there is no need to ```exposes some functions for the "outside world"```. Also if a function is useful for several situations (for example several components), why you don't define that function in a separate file like ```functions.scss```?

Comment: because I would like to keep the code in logically wise parts. For example, my component could use a function that can change it's (the components) colors, that's still only a function that should be used by that component, or by other components that rely on that component, why should I put it in a globally available file, which has no relation whatsoever to the specific component?

Comment: updated my original question, with an example based on the above, only with a `@mixin` not a `@function`. I could think of a `@function` as well, just this was may express more naturally on what I would want to achieve.

Comment: OK, But what is your problem with using ```@use 'componentFunctions' as componentFunctions;``` in all that **other components that rely on that component**. You can make all functions that are used in this tree of components in a separate file (like **componentFunctions** file) and use it in all files of this tree. Sass docs says it should be OK, because **styles loaded this way will be included exactly once**.

Comment: my problem is, that instead of just including a component, with all of it's parts, I need to separately include a component, **and one or more of it's parts** when I want to use said parts in the file. As I stated in my original question, I am aware that I can include the mixins separately in my main file, I just want to find a solution, where I don't have to, as I don't find it logical.

Comment: I am sorry, I've did not state that in my original question, but nonetheless, I know that I can `@use` any file, and it will only be included once (or zero times, in case of underscored `_` components, as those do not generate code at all)